# Getting the value of an input field, which gets dynamically placed (not via js) onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jsp

I spent a few hours searching and trying stuff out, but I can't get my ajax form submit working. (I'm also really not a front-end person, so sorry if I mess up my explanation)

I have a site that dynamically inserts HTML content (through JSP, not javascript). I have a simple form with a submit button inside that inserted html. This is the piece of html I have:

```
<tr>
    <td>Change stock by:</td>
    <td>
        <div id="quantityinput" class="field has-addons">
            <div class="control"> <input class="input" type="text" id="mutation" placeholder="0">

            </div>
            <a href="#" class="button is-success" id="quantityConfirm">update</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I managed to link the button to the right ajax-function, like this:
(.editor__product is the direct parent of the form, but there is a bunch of non-form information there)

```
$(".editor__product").on("click", "#quantityConfirm", function ($) {



    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/bullet-journal/mutateitem',
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                product_mutate: product_mutate
            }
        })
        .done(function (html) {

            $('#main').load(document.URL + ' #main');
            $(".editor__product").load('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/refreshinfo');
        });


});
```

But the problem is, I have no idea how to get the value from my "#mutation" input field. I tried various ways to append it to my document and get it, but it either results in a new text field somewhere on the bottom of my page, or simply in a NULL value error. I have more ajax forms in the website which work fine, but they use elements that are hardcoded.

Every solution I could find was specifically for javascript-generated content, while my input doesn't get generated by javascript.

How would I go about extracting the value from my mutation input? Thanks a lot for any advice, the browser console isn't very helpful.

Comment: a simple way of getting a value form an input field is `$(elem).val()` (as you're using jquery). But the confusion is you're saying that you're trying to append it to the document. So please clarify this ==are you appending the input filed or it's already in the document? if you're appending it than you have to use event delegation to get the value if it's not the case use the method I mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value using js :

```
var mutation = document.getElementById('mutation').value;
```

or with jquery

```
var mutation = $('#mutation').val();
```

And pass mutation in your data or do what you need to with it

Comment: I swear to god that that is the first thing I tried, which didn't work.  Turns out I was troubleshooting a cached page instead of my actual changes.

Your solution worked. Better figure out now how to turn the browsers refresh button into an actual full refresh.